# Container already stopped error on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I recently started with Amazon ECS. I created a very basic docker image with the following details:

```
FROM centos:7
LABEL name="MRK" \
    vendor="MRK" \
    build-date="20170529"

#Install required packages
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install java
RUN yum -y install ImageMagick

#Copy server code to container image
COPY my_server /opt/my_server

#Run my_server/startup.sh on startup
RUN /opt/my_server/startup.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I pushed this to my repo which ECS created for me. Later I followed the following steps as per the getting started on AWS ECS console:

1. Created a cluster with one container instance via AWS console.
2. Created a task definition where under container I provided
   information about my pushed image.
3. Created a service for this task
   definition to be run at minimum count of 1.

The service executes but is throwing error of "*Essential container in task exited*". I tried to find any other error details on console but couldn't find. I sshed to the container instance and I see this error in docker logs:

```
time="2017-05-30T11:41:45.298855693Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.17/containers/8a0dcb0853120221298f009addf52f463463b5632303843c3184515e1676a569/stop returned error: Container 8a0dcb0853120221298f009addf52f463463b5632303843c3184515e1676a569 is already stopped"
```

Doing a docker ps also shows only 'amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest'. while doing a docker ps -a shows list of all recent run containers.

I tried checking the logs for these recent runs by doing docker logs  but it doesn't show any error.

I am bit stuck here due to insufficient error information and not sure what might be causing this. Can anyone suggest if I am missing something which is required for this setup?

Comment: Sounds like you need more logging. Enable Cloudwatch logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

Comment: Can you share what the task definition looks like? I wonder if the Entrypoint or CMD you are running is just exiting. `/bin/bash` in your Dockerfile stands out to me.

Comment: I enabled the cloudwatch logs. That is very helpful. 

I am not sure why it was terminating container process but I updated my dockerFile by adding this in end and removing Run for this command worked for me: 

`CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/my_server/startup.sh"]`

Now it launches container, executes this script and destroy the container which is what I required.

Comment: I think previously it was failing due to the fact that `RUN /opt/my_server/startup.sh` was supposed to be executed as shell script and it was not able to run it and expecting full path to be given e.g. /bin/bash, now for CMD I am using it as `["/bin/bash", "/opt/my_server/startup.sh"]`.